# Create users in Oracle, MySQL databases using Springboot - Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am very new to Springboot and Spring Data JPA and working on a use case where I am required to create users in different databases.
The application will receive 2 inputs from a queue - username and database name.
Using this I have to provision the given user in the given database.
I am unable to understand the project architecture. 
Since the query I need to run will be of the format - create user ABC identified by password;
How should the project look like in terms of model class, repositories etc? Since I do not have an actual table against which the query will be run, do I need a model class since there will be no column mappings happening as such.

TLDR - Help in architecturing  Springboot-Spring Data JPA application configured with multiple data sources to run queries of the format : create user identified by password

I have been using this GitHub repo for reference - https://github.com/jahe/spring-boot-multiple-datasources/blob/master/src/main/java/com/foobar

Answer (score 2):

I'll be making some assumptions here:

- your database of choice is `Oracle`, based on provided syntax: `create user ABC identified by password`
- you want to create and list users
- your databases are well-known and defined in JNDI

I can't just provide code unfortunately as setting it up would take me some work, but I can give you the gist of it.

---

Method 1: using JPA

- first, create a `User` entity and a corresponding `UserRepository`. Bind the entity to the `all_users` table. The primary key will probably be either the `USERNAME` or the `USER_ID` column... but it doesn't really matter as you won't be doing any insert into that table.
- to create and a user, add a dedicated method to your own `UserRepository` specifying the user creation query within a `@NativeQuery` annotation. It should work out-of-the-box.
- to list users you shouldn't need to do anything, as your entity at this point is already bound to the correct table. Just call the appropriate (and already existing) method in your repository.

The above in theory covers the creation and listing of users in a given database using JPA.

If you have a limited number of databases (and therefore a limited number of well-known JNDI datasources) at this point you can proceed as shown in the GitHub example you referenced, by providing different `@Configuration` classes for each different `DataSource`, each with the related (identical) repository living in a separate package.

You will of course have to add some logic that will allow you to appropriately select the `JpaRepository` to use for the operations.

This will lead to some code duplication and works well only if the needs remain very simple over time. That is: it works if all your "microservice" will ever have to do is this create/list (and maybe delete) of users and the number of datasources remains small over time, as each new datasource will require you to add new classes, recompile and redeploy the microservice.

Alternatively, try with the approach proposed here:
https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/11/16/connect-multiple-jpa-repositories-using

---

Personally however I would throw JPA out of the window completely as it's anything but easy to dynamically configure arbitrary `DataSource` objects and reconfigure the repositories to work each time against a different `DataSource` and the above solution will force you to constant maintenance over such a simple application.

What I would do would be sticking with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` initialising it by using `JndiTemplate`. Example:

```
void createUser(String username, String password, String database) {
    DataSource ds = (new JndiTemplate()).lookup(database);
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("USERNAME", username);
    params.put("PASSWORD", password);
    npjt.execute('create user :USERNAME identified by :PASSWORD', params);
}

List<Map<String, Object>> listUsers() {
    DataSource ds = (new JndiTemplate()).lookup(database);
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate();
    return npjt.queryForList("select * from all_users", new HashMap<>());
}
```

Provided that your container has the JNDI datasources already defined, the above code should cover both the creation of a user and the listing of users. No need to define entities or repositories or anything else. You don't even have to define your datasources in a spring `@Configuration`. The above code (which you will have to test) is really all you need so you could wire it in a `@Controller` and be done with it.

If you don't use JNDI it's no problem either: you can use `HikariCP` to define your datasources, providing the additional arguments as parameters.

This solution will work no matter how many different datasources you have and won't need redeployment unless you really have to work on its features. Plus, it doesn't need the developer to know JPA and it doesn't need to spread the configuration all over the place.

Comment: What if some Grant commands need to execute after user creation

Comment: You create another method similar to createUser and call it afterwards. At least that seems the most straightforward solution.