# Use the same DAO for running same query across multiple databases?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dao

I have a use case where the same native query : create user identified by passwd needs to be executed across multiple databases ( mostly oracle ) depending on the input from user. Will this require a separate dao (repository) for each database or can I create 1 DAO and re-use it across?
I am configuring the different databases via java-based configuration to get the jdbc-database url etc and have marked one of them as primary. I don't want to create multiple DAOs as all will contain the same piece of code.
If the same DAO can be reused, how do I specify on which database to run the query at?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source

Comment: No need to create multiple questions.
I modified the answer to your question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319530/create-users-in-oracle-mysql-databases-using-springboot-spring-data-jpa

I provided in that answer a link that explains how to do what you need in JPA as well.